# Parametric equation of $x^y=y^x$ curve

Tags: plane-curves

What is the easiest/most natural way to parametrize the following curve?

$$\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^{+2}\mid x^y=y^x, x\neq y\}\cup\{(e,e)\}$$

The best I could do was taking it apart, and for $x>y$ use $y(x)=\sqrt[x]{x}^{\sqrt[x]{x}^{\sqrt[x]{x}^{.....}}}$, but I see no theoretical reason why I should break it into parts, since the curve *looks so nice*.

Maybe the niceness of the curve is just an illusion, and in fact the $x<y$ and $x>y$ cases must be considered separately?

EDIT:$$(x,y)=(e^{t/(e^t-1)},e^{t/(1-e^{-t})})\quad t \in\Bbb R$$ This is a very nice parametrization, but still doesn't include $(e,e)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the edit of my question, and then poined out by WimC, the best result is
$$x(t) = \exp\left(\dfrac{t}{e^t-1}\right) \quad y(t)=\exp\left(\dfrac{t}{1-e^{-t}}\right)$$For the simplest way to obtain this, take marty cohen's answer and substitute $r=e^t$. Or, alternatively, see mjqxxxx's post.

For $t=0$ we can holomorphically extend this function by defining $x(0)=y(0)=e$.

Answer (score 6):

Suppose you take $x=e^{r\cos\theta}$ and $y=e^{r\sin\theta}$ for $\theta\in(0,\pi/2)$.  Then you want to solve
$$
e^{r\cos\theta e^{r\sin\theta}}=e^{r\sin\theta e^{r\cos\theta}}
$$
for $r$.  Taking the logarithm of both sides and dividing through by $r$ (losing the $r=0$ solution in the process) gives
$$
\cos\theta e^{r\sin\theta} = \sin\theta e^{r\cos\theta},
$$
hence
$$
\tan\theta = e^{r(\sin\theta - \cos\theta)},
$$
or
$$
r(\sin\theta - \cos\theta) = \ln\tan\theta.
$$
This is satisfied for $\theta=\pi/4$, for any $r$, which gives the line $y=x$.  The piece you're interested in is given by
$$
r=\frac{\ln\tan\theta}{\sin\theta - \cos\theta}.
$$
Plugging this back in, you have
$$
(x,y)=\left(\exp\left(\frac{\ln\tan\theta}{\tan\theta - 1}\right), \exp\left(\frac{\ln\tan\theta}{1-\cot\theta}\right) \right) \\
=\left(\left(\tan\theta\right)^{\frac{1}{\tan\theta-1}}, \left(\tan\theta\right)^{\frac{1}{1-\cot\theta}}\right),
$$
or simply
$$
(x,y)=\left(t^{1/(t-1)}, t^{t/(t-1)}\right)
$$
for $t \in (0,\infty)$.  (Yes, there is a hole at $t=1$.)

Comment: Can you use a connected $\theta$ domain without hitting $y=x$?

Comment: @dfeuer: I don't see how.  But there's not really a problem with this parameterization; it's analytic at $t=1$.  Just looking at $\ln x(t)$, you have $\ln t / (t-1)$, which is $\ln(1+(t-1)) / (t-1) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} (t-1)^k / (k+1)$.

Answer (score 6):

I've done this here before, but it's quicker 
to write it again
than to try to find it.

Let $y = rx$.
$x^y = y^x$
becomes
$x^{rx} = (rx)^x$
or
$x^r = rx$
or
$x^{r-1} = r$
or
$x = r^{1/(r-1)}$
and
$y = rx = r^{1+1/(r-1)}
=r^{r/(r-1)}
$.

If $r=1$,
all values of $x$ work
since the condition is
$x^{r-1} = r$.

Comment: Maybe I'm dense, but I can't make head or tail of this.

Comment: @dfeuer: after substitution, take the x-th root, then divide by x, then take the (r-1)-th root

Answer (score 5):

**Edit:** I just see that you already mention this one in your question...  But unlike you state there, it *does* include $(e,e)$ namely for $t=0$.

Basically a reparameterisation of other answers but $$ x(t) = \exp\left(\dfrac{t}{e^t-1}\right) \quad y(t)=\exp\left(\dfrac{t}{1-e^{-t}}\right) $$ for $t\in \mathbb{R}$ seems to be a nice and symmetric one.  Note that these expressions extend nicely over $t=0$ and $$\left(x(0), y(0)\right) = (e,e)$$ and $$ \left(x(-t), y(-t)\right) = \left(y(t), x(t)\right).$$

Comment: Its limit at $t=0$ is $(e,e)$, but it is not itself defined there.

Comment: @dfeuer  It does not show in this notation perhaps but it extends even holomorphically over $t=0$ in much the same way as $\sin(t)/t$ does.  It is not uncommon to use this notation to mean the extended function, as I do in this case.

Comment: Is there a way to reformulate this expression so that we don't have this anomaly at $t=0$?

Comment: @Dave  I don't think so.  But again, in (complex) function theory it is very common to extend implicitly over all removable singularities.  And a tip: it is perfectly fine to post your own answer and accept it!  (Instead of stating this result in the question.)

Comment: @WimC I didn't post it as an answer because I wasn't satisfied with it. Now that I see that it's the best one could get, I think I will.

Comment: Write it in the form  $$x(t)=\exp\left(1/\int_0^1 e^{t\tau}\ d\tau\right),\quad y(t)=\exp\left(1/\int_0^1 e^{-t\tau}\ d\tau\right)\ .$$

Answer (score 3):

I can't really answer your question, but I think I can see why it might split like that:

$x^y=y^x$ generally means that
$e^{y\log x}=e^{x\log y}$, which occurs when $y\log x = x\log y$, so 
$\frac {\log y}y=\frac{\log x}x$.

If you graph $f(x)=\frac{\log x}x$, you will see that the only region where $f$ is not injective is $(1,\infty)$, in which $f$ first rises rapidly from $0$ to a maximum of $1/e$ at $x=e$ and then declines gradually forever, approaching $0$.

So giving $y$ in terms of $x$ or $x$ in terms of $y$ means giving one point in terms of the other, and it's not surprising that odd things would happen when they cross.