# $f(n)=$, for even integer’s $n$, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^x}{^nx} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, power-towers

$f(n)=$, for even integer’s $n$, $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^x}{^nx} dx$$

$^n x$ is the tetrative function or ‘power tower’, which when $n=\infty$ can also be written in terms of y, as $x= e^\frac{ln(y)}{y}$, I mention this only because this may be doable in standard notation if taken in the dy world but I dont know how to effectively translate this equation.

For reference I am a sophomore in highschool, and havent been formally taught calculus, so my notation may not be perfect

Specifically the even $n$’s because any odd $n$ will not converge

I have a series of approximations which point towards an answer but I was curious if theres a was a way to either find an exact answer or if there was some special function or sum I was unaware of which could help

$f(2)\approx 6.34981$
$f(4)\approx 3.9184$
$f(6)\approx 3.74148$
$f(8)\approx 3.6939$
$f(10)\approx 3.6762$
$f(12)\approx 3.66844$
After this my wolfram alpha runs out of computation power and time, but it is clearly approaching some value.

Additionally the function can be wrote as just $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^x}{^{2n}x} dx$$
for any integer $n$ but I left it as the original so you could better understand my framing when approaching the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We'll try to use the [dominated convergence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem) to bring the limit into the integral and hopefully get something more manageable. For the boundedness part, it can be shown (like in [this reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1908.05559.pdf), for example) that $^{2n}x \ge 1/e$ for $x \in \left[0,e^{\frac1e}\right]$ and diverges to infinity for the other possible values.

Now, from the same reference we know that $^{2n}x$ converges to a branch of $y=x^{x^y}$ for $0<x<e^{-e}$. Using [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3836908/695196) we can thus say that
$\frac{1}{^{2n}x}$ goes to $y=0$ for $x>e^{\frac1e}$, for $e^{-e}\le x \le e^{\frac1e}$ goes to $y=e^{W_0\left( -\ln(x)\right)}$ and for $0<x<e^{-e}$ it goes to $x = e^{y W_{-1}\left( \frac{-\ln(y)}{y}\right)}$, where $W_k(z)$ is the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

This allows us to get an integral representation for your limit in terms of the $W$ function. By denoting $I_n = \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^x}{^{2n}x}\mathrm{d}x$ we get
$$
I_n \to e^{1+e^{-e}}-1 - \int_{1}^{e} e^{ e^{y W_{-1}\left( \frac{-\ln(y)}{y}\right)}}\, \mathrm{d}y+\int_{e^{-e}}^{e^{\frac1e}} e^{x +W_0\left( -\ln(x)\right)} \,\mathrm{d}x \approx 3.67054
$$
where the last evaluation is obtained using [W.A.](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=NIntegrate%5BE%5E%28x+%2B+ProductLog%5B-Log%5Bx%5D%5D%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+E%5E%28-E%29%2C+E%5E%281%2FE%29%7D%5D+-+NIntegrate%5BE%5EE%5E%28y+ProductLog%5B-1%2C+-%28Log%5By%5D%2Fy%29%5D%29%2C+%7By%2C+1%2C+E%7D%5D+-+1+%2B+E%5E%281+%2B+E%5E%28-E%29%29)

---

Alternatively, you can use the parametrizations also given in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3836908/695196) to get an integral representation for the value of the limit that doesn't use the $W$ function explicitly. Although this method does work, it results in very ugly integral expressions (specifically [this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_%280%29%5E%281%29+%5B+t%5E%28-t%2F%281-t%29%29e%5E%28t%5E%28%28t%5E%7B-t%2F%281-t%29%7D%29%2F%281-t%29%29%29*D%5Bt%5E%281%2F%28t%5E%28t%2F%281+-+t%29%29+%281+-+t%29%29%29%2C+t%5D%5D+dt) and [this one](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=int_%281%2Fe%29%5E%28e%29+%5Be%5E%28t%5E%281%2Ft%29%29+t%5E%28-1+%2B+1%2Ft%29+%281%2Ft%5E2+-+log%28t%29%2Ft%5E2%29%5D+dt)), but this method also confirms the previous value of $3.67054...$ as the limit.

As a last bonus, it's easier to plot a parametric curve rather than a special function, so here's a [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/odijfoo9rt) of the previously given parametrizations alongside $\frac{e^x}{^{100}x}$:

[image: Graph]